# Resetting knockout.js value from a dropdown field depending of another one

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a set of dropdown fields (using knockout.js) that is "dynamically" building two javascript functions that I use on my website and that I am triggering with a link.

The first function is building perfectly.

The second function uses the dropdown "Duration" to make the "VIP Plus 1 year" or "VIP Plus 2 years" options to appear/disappear and build the second function.

The problem is when I select "1 year" in "Duration" and then "Vip Plus 1" option, the correct sku is added to my second function, BUT if I change my mind and select "2 years" in Duration, the value stays in the second function and is added to the new "VIP Plus 2 years" sku in my output.

Ideally, if nothing is selected from the "VIP Plus 1 year" or "VIP Plus 2 years" dropdowns, the second function would just not appear at all.

This is probably very easy to solve but since I am a beginner in js, I'm stucked there...

See my preview at http://jsfiddle.net/X6fJ5/3/

```
<p>Membership : <select name="no1" data-bind="value: membership" />
                <option value="NEW">New membership</option>
                <option value="RENEW">Renew membership</option>
                <option value="GIFT">Gift membership</option>
                </select>
</p>
<p>Category : <select name="no2" data-bind="value: category" />
                <option value="1400">VIP Individual</option>
                <option value="709">VIP Family</option>
                <option value="703">VIP ang Guest</option>
                <option value="1389">VIP Student</option>
                </select>
</p>
<p>Duration : <select name="no3" data-bind="value: duration" id="opts" onchange="showForm();" />
                <option value="1" selected="selected">1 an</option>
                <option value="2">2 ans</option>
                </select>
</p>
<div id="f1" style="display:none">
<p>VIP Plus 1 year : <select name="no4" data-bind="value: vipplus1" id="opts" />
                <option value="" selected="selected">No thanks</option>
                <option value="DON-VIPPLUS1-125">VIP Plus 1</option>
                <option value="DON-VIPPLUS1-250">VIP Plus 2</option>
                <option value="DON-VIPPLUS1-500">VIP Plus 3</option>
                </select>
</div>
<div id="f2" style="display:none">
VIP Plus 2 years : <select name="no5" data-bind="value: vipplus2" id="opts" />
                <option value="" selected="selected">No thanks</option>
                <option value="DON-VIPPLUS2-250">VIP Plus 1</option>
                <option value="DON-VIPPLUS2-500">VIP Plus 2</option>
                <option value="DON-VIPPLUS2-1000">VIP Plus 3</option>
                </select>
</p></div>
<br />
<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-bind="attr: { onclick: mvipsku }">Add to cart</a>
<br />
<h3><span data-bind="html: mvipsku"> </span></h3>
<script type="text/javascript">
var ViewModel = function(membership, category, duration, vipplus1, vipplus2) {
    this.membership = ko.observable(membership);
    this.category = ko.observable(category);
    this.duration = ko.observable(duration);
    this.vipplus1 = ko.observable(vipplus1);
    this.vipplus2 = ko.observable(vipplus2);    

    this.mvipsku = ko.computed(function() {
        return "addMembershipToCart('" + "MVIP-" + this.membership() + "-" + this.duration() + "-" + this.category() + "');" + "<br />" + "addProductToCart('" + this.vipplus1() + this.vipplus2() + "');";
    }, this);

};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel()); // This makes Knockout get to work

function showForm() {
    var selopt = document.getElementById("opts").value;
    if (selopt == 1) {
        document.getElementById("f1").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("f2").style.display = "none";   
    }
    if (selopt == 2) {
        document.getElementById("f2").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("f1").style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should subscribe to the change of `duration` and clear the apprpropriate VIP Plus setting:

```
self.duration.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    if(newValue == '1') {
        self.vipplus2(null);
    } else if(newValue == '2') {
        self.vipplus1(null);
    }
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/348hb/)